# Find the area of the conical shell that has an equation $ z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} $ using polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I need to find the area of the conical shell that has an equation $$ z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, $$
where $0 \leq a < b$ and $a \leq z \leq b$

What I have found by far is that our $z=r$, thus $a \leq r \leq b$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

Which means that I will have to integrate $$ \int_0^{2\pi} \int_a^b r^2drd\theta $$

Please correct me if I made a mistake. I feel like either the bounds of integration or the function specification might be wrong.

Comment: What's area formula?

Comment: @MyGlasses, That's the point, I have a difficulty evaluating it, so I suggested this option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\text{area(A)}=\iint_A\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}dxdy$$
where
$$\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}=\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{2y}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)^2}=\sqrt{2}$$
then
$$\text{area}=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_a^b r\sqrt{2}drd\theta$$

Comment: Thanks man, you are the best, so please explain now how you found the function under the radical

Comment: I know how to simplify, but how did you get that formula under the radical? What's the intuition behind it?

Comment: The first one is the area formula you can find in calculus books.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area#General_formula_for_surface_area